# how can I have a function with a 2D array as an argument whereas the array has a parameter/dimension that I want to change?

Tags: c++, arrays

(I'm a student and this is my first time posting so go easy on me.)
I want to create a function that takes a 2D array as an argument and in that array, I'd like to have a variable that I want to modify later in the code.  This is the closest thing to an example of what I want:

```
int size;  //the variable I want to change later
void function(int[][size]);

int main(){
    cin >> size;
    int array[size][size];  //the array I'm using with the variable as a parameter
    function(array)
}

void function(int array[][size]){
    //Do thing....
}
```

The code above does give me an error (array bound is not an integer constant) so if I make the variable a constant it will compile as seen here:

```
const int size = 10;
void function(int[][size]);

int main(){
    int array[size][size];
    function(array)
}

void function(int array[][size]){
    //Do thing....
}
```

This does compile like I said, but now I can't modify the variable and need to declare its value in the code beforehand.  I assume that the variable needs to be global so that I can use it in the function, and with that said, I can't get pointers to work either most likely because it's a global variable and not a local one.  Here's an example of something I tried, but got an error (invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’):

```
const int size = 10;
void function(int[][size]);

int main(){
    int *other = &size;
    *other = 5;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please try `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for your dynamic 2d array.

Comment: static arrays aren't resizeable. In C++, you also have to use a constant size that can't be a variable that gets set at run-time.

Comment: Yes, that is how types work in C++ -- they must be known at compile time and cannot be changed at runtime. (The type in this case is `int [][size]`, an array of arrays of fixed size known at compile time.) You'll need to rethink what you want in your code, possibly writing your own class to serve as your two-dimensional array.

Comment: You said you want to modify a variable. Can you tell which variable.? You want to modify passed array or any other ?

Comment: The answer will depend on whether you can use STL containers like `std::vector` or whether you will need to use old dynamic allocation. The C++ standard does not provide *Variable Length Arrays* (VLAs) but some compilers do provide them by non-standard compiler extensions. (they should be avoided for that reason even if your compiler does). So do you have any limitations on what you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Plain ol' arrays aren't resizeable in C++. Even more frustrating, their size has to be a constant - you can't make the size a variable that gets set at runtime. Ever more frustrating, the size you put in an array that's a function parameter is a *constraint*, and it's not even enforced. It's just decor.

As it was hinted in the comments, `std::vector<TYPE>` is the go-to "resizeable array" in C++. You can create a vector like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> my_int_array;
}
```

And you can resize it like this:

```cpp
int new_size = 42;
my_int_array.resize(new_size);
```

And you can pass it to a function *by reference*(see the `&`) so that changes to myint_array inside the function affect it outside the function.

```cpp
void my_awesome_function(std::vector<int>& int_array);

my_awesome_function(my_int_array);
```

So let's say you have a 2D matrix, implemented as a vector of vectors:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix = { { 1,2,3 }, { 4,5,6 } }
```

If you want to change the number of columns, you have to resize each row array:

```cpp
int new_column_count = 10;
for (auto& row : matrix) {
    row.resize(new_column_count );
}
```

You can pass around `matrix` by reference (e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>&`) and resize it when you need to.

Comment: In your *"change the number of columns"* explanation, you may want to caution that you can only increase the number of columns without having to temporarily store values in columns that would be removed in attempting to shrink the number of columns. (but good overview of the choices with `std::vector` available)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but that sentence is a little dense for me to grok. Can you break it down for me?

Comment: Sorry, sure, if `new_column_count` is less than the original number of columns in that row, you will truncate the row at `new_column_count` integers. See: [std::vector<T,Allocator>::resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)